# Search tabs in laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, datatables

I'm building an app in Laravel and everything is working fine except one thing.

I want to make some search tabs (don't know if this is the right term to use) so it is easier to search for information. My objective is to do something like this:

[image: Pic1]

And this is what I have:

[image: Pic2]

This is the code of my page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
@endsection

@section('js')
<script src="{{ asset('js/sweetalert.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.min.js') }}" defer></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span>
            <i class="fas fa-building"></i>
            <strong class="text-uppercase">Gestão de Obras</strong>
        </span>

        <a href="{{ route('constructions.create') }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            Criar obra
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered guaca-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Referência</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Morada</th>
                    <th>Terminada em</th>
                    <th class="guaca-table-head-actions" style="text-align:center">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach ($constructions as $construction)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $construction->reference }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $construction->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($construction->description, 50, '...') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($construction->address, 100, '...') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($construction->has_ended)
                                {{ $construction->end_date }}
                            @else
                                -
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            @if (!$construction->is_system)
                                    <a href="{{ route('constructions.edit', $construction->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
                                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    @if (!$construction->has_ended)
                                        <!-- BOTÂO DE TERMINAR OBRAS -->
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#end-modal-{{ $construction->id }}">
                                            <i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <!-- MODAL DE TERMINAR OBRAS -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="end-modal-{{ $construction->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
                                            aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('constructions.end', ['id' => $construction->id]) }}">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                                                                Terminar obra
                                                            </h5>
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <strong>
                                                                Referência:
                                                            </strong>
                                                            <div>
                                                                {{ $construction->reference }} 
                                                            </div>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <strong>
                                                                Nome:
                                                            </strong>
                                                            <div>
                                                                {{ $construction->name }} 
                                                            </div>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <strong>
                                                                Morada:
                                                            </strong>
                                                            <div>
                                                                {{ $construction->address }} 
                                                            </div>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <strong>
                                                                Data de Término:
                                                            </strong>
                                                            <input id="end_date" 
                                                                type="date" class="form-control datepicker {{ $errors->has('end_date') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" 
                                                                name="end_date" value="{{ old('end_date') }}" required>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Terminar obra</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                    <form method="POST" class="delete-form" 
                                        action="{{ route('constructions.destroy', $construction->id) }}">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('delete')
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">
                                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                            @else
                                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                    SISTEMA
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

I have tried to create a **app.js** inside the assets folder and then inside the JS folder and this is my code, but it's not working:

```
require('./bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function () {
var $datepickers = $('.datepicker');

$datepickers.each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        language: 'pt',
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        useCurrent: true
    });
});

//ao mexer na dropdown no formulario de COMPRAS
$('.form-group-slider').on('change', function () {
    var $target = $(this.dataset.sliderTarget);

    if (!!this.value) {
        $target.slideUp();
    } else {
        $target.slideDown();
    }
});

$('.delete-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    if ($form.data('allow') !== true) {
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
          title: "Tem a certeza que pretende apagar?",
          text: "Esta operação é irreversível!",
          icon: "warning",
          dangerMode: true,
          buttons: ["Cancelar", "Sim, tenho a certeza"],
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
            $form.data('allow', true);
            $form.submit();
          }
        });
    }
});

$('.select2').each(function () {
    $(this).select2();
});

$('.guaca-table').each(function () {
    var $table = $(this);

    if (!$table) {
        return;
    }

    var initialHeadCount = $table.find('th').length;
    var orderableArray = [];

    for (var i = initialHeadCount - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        orderableArray.push(i);
    }


    $('.guaca-table thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '.guaca-table thead' );
    $('.guaca-table thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i) {
        var $th = $(this);

        if ($th.hasClass('guaca-table-head-actions')) {
            return;
        }

        var title = $th.text();
        $th.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Pesquisar ' + title + '" />');

        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (dataTable.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                dataTable.column(i).search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
    });

    dataTable = $table.DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: orderableArray, orderable: true },
            { targets: ["_all"], orderable: false }
        ],
        language: {
            decimal: "",
            emptyTable: "Não existem items.",
            info: "Mostrar _START_ a _END_ de um total de _TOTAL_ items",
            infoEmpty: "Mostrar 0 a 0 de um total de 0 items",
            infoFiltered: "(Filtrado de um total de _MAX_ items)",
            infoPostFix: "",
            thousands: ",",
            lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ items",
            loadingRecords: "A carregar...",
            processing: "A processar...",
            search: "Pesquisar:",
            zeroRecords: "A pesquisa não retornou resultados.",
            paginate: {
                first: "Primeiro",
                last: "Último",
                next: "Próximo",
                previous: "Anterior"
            },
            aria: {
                sortAscending: "Ativar para ordenar coluna por ordem ascendente.",
                sortDescending: "Ativar para ordenar coluna por ordem descendente."
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referencing in your "want" is part of "DataTables" there is a laravel package for integrating the server side of DataTables. ( https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables ).

Please see www.datatables.net to learn how to set it up like you want.  It is a very powerful table package with several different ways to initialize it.  It does not appear that datatables is actually initializing the table - likely you have an error in your datatables initialization code.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's been a few days and I haven't manage to understand even how to set it up. Every video I watch teaches how to set up the datatables from the beginning of a new project but not when the tables are already created.

Comment: Start small.  

$('#tableid').DataTables();  <-  can you update your question to show what that does for me?